# Improving scalability with WCF services

Tags: wcf, performance, architecture, scalability

We are thinking about splitting our app into a UI app, and a WCF service layer (which will encompass all other layers; service/data etc...) to allow for various WCF layers to be deployed to improve performance, and scalability.

We are looking to create an application that will scale successfully to around 600-800 users successfully (Constant use) without hampering performance. We ideally would like to be able to deploy a new business layer to increase performance.

Does anyone have any proven scenarios of this working? Or could anyone offer any advice on how I should approach this?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question isn't anwserable with seeing your code or knowing all requirements. Application achitecure is not just appling a technoligy and then you have scalability and performance for free.

Comment: I've added some extra requirements to the question, we are looking to create an application that will scale successfully to around 6-800 users without any performance hits, and should they hit performance, we would ideally like to drop in a new BL segment, not a full deployment.

Does that help?

Comment: Have you looked at [StockTrader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.aspx)?

Comment: Just taking a look into this now..